# How to ssh and sftp into an ec2 behind an elastic load balacer without elastic ip address

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to figure out a way to ssh into an ec2 instance behind an elastic load balancer without assigning the ec2 instance an Elastic IP

Usually I would assign an Elastic IP onto an ec2 instance and just SSH and SFTP through that way but is their another  way  ,I can ssh and sftp without assigning it an elastic ip through PuTTy?

Answer (score 10):

I tried this configuration - the ELB port to be 2222 and the Instance port to 22. It worked for me. For simplicity I used the same SG for both EC2 and ELB.

**Similarly you can route the PORT `2220` to `20`, `2221` to `21` like this for `SFTP`**

1. TCP Port 2222(ELB) to 22 (Instance)
   [image]
2. Open Putty and enter the ELB DNS with Port 2222 [Be sure if the 2222 is opened to your exit IP of office / public IP via. the SG]
   [image]
3. Get the Connection Established [the IP 14.0.1.87 is ELB's ID and not the public IP of my machine]
   [image]

Comment: In 2019 this is called a "Classic load balancer".  If you use an 'Application Load Balancer' then it does not give an option for arbitrary port numbers.

Comment: Should we use NLB option then with similar setup?

Comment: NLB would be the way. Though I don't understand why we need to set different ports on the load balancer. Why can't we forward port 22 on the LB to port 22 on the target instance?

Comment: as @JHamm says, I don't see why you wouldn't just use 22-22 ???